# Limit excerpt by characters in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Right so this seems to have been asked a few times but I cannot seem to find definitive working answer.

Currently I am trying to limit my post title and post excerpt on my WP website.

I have managed to trim the titles by character using

```
function custom_trim_my_title( $title ) {
if ( strlen( $title ) >= 72 && ! is_singular() ) {
$title = substr( $title, 0, 72 ) . '...';
return $title;
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'custom_trim_my_title' );
```

And that seems to be working okay but I can't seem to get it to work for the excerpt.

I was using this word count:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

But the longer words still made it look messy so I need a character count and have tried this:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit');
function excerpt_char_limit($e){
    return substr($e,0,50);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that your theme file have the_excerpt() print function? May be it use some own method using post_content instead of excerpt. Please share the code piece of your theme where your excerpts are printed

Comment: I hate to say this but I am just a beginner and don't know where to find that information. The first 2 work just not the 3rd one. I can see if I can spot anything in the files but I'm not really sure where to look.

Comment: Just in case. Try using add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit',999); instead. (i don't think if it will affect or not, without seeing the code)

Comment: Amazing! that worked - I add the ellipses at the end like so:

add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit',999); 
function excerpt_char_limit($e){
    return substr($e,0,200) . '...';
}

Comment: Do you want to post that as the answer and I can accept it as the solution? Thanks very much

Comment: Is it possible to make it include the spaces?

Comment: Yes. i will do it now. It should include spaces by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

`add_filter('the_excerpt','excerpt_char_limit',999);`

instead. It is just in case if some other filter prevents your filter. (999 means executing later than other filters)